# Is painted vs has been painted

Tags: grammar

Why this sentence is correct:

"That is the house whose door **is painted** brown"

Shouldn't it be :

that is the house whose door **has** ***been painted*** brown"

I mean if "is painted" is a passive voice based on the English I've learned so far it should be used in sentence like this :

This door is painted every day

So as a non-native this use of "**is painted**" here is vague to me

Can somebody explain this please thanks in advance

Comment: What color ***is*** the door? The door ***is*** brown.  Why is the door brown?  The door ***is*** painted.  ->  The door is painted brown.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are confused because  we have two different uses of 'painted' here. There is the verb which describes the process of painting something, even if the action is in the past (I had a decorator come yesterday and he painted my door brown) and the adjectival usage where we use 'painted' to describe the condition of the door after the action of painting it has been completed (You can tell which is my house becasue it's the one where the door is painted brown).

This use of the same word both a verb and as an adjective is actually quite common. In terms of doors we can also do it with the word 'lock' ("The door is locked when we leave" as opposed to "I can't get in because the door is locked")

We can also do it with food ("I sliced the bread so that it was ready for toasting" and "I want a loaf of sliced bread, please.")

Comment: This is the distinction. One practical difference is that "the door is painted red" tells you what the door is like now, while "the door has been painted red" tells you about something that happened in the past (but it doesn't necessarily mean that the door will currently be painted red).

Comment: @StuartF That's a good point. If a brown door was chipped, scratched or sanded down someone looking at it might see some old red paint being revealed and say "This door _has been_ painted red at one time"

Comment: @BoldBen thank you very much for your explanation . let me get this straight so here "is" actually is the main verb and painted is an adjective and we don't have passive voice here at all am I right?

Comment: @SeyyedhadiMosavi Basically, yes. Saying "The door is painted brown" is a bit like saying "The door is made of wood". Obviously the door was actually made from pieces of wood at some time (that is the passive voice) but that could have been hundreds of years ago. When we are discussing the door now we say "The door is made of wood" to describe its current state. If we say "The door was made from old ship's timbers" that is the passive voice and refers to the time when the door was actually constructed.